# Scipy.optimize_curve_fit says that the covariance of the parameters cannot be estimated

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve

I am trying to perform a curve fit in order to estimate values of the parameters of a function for a set of data using scipy.optimize.curve_fit. My data has uncertainties in both the x and y data. When I look up the documentation for scipy.optimize.curve_fit, it says that sigma=the uncertainty of the y values. But when I put that in, I get an OptimizeWarning: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
How do I fix this?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frequency = [111.11, 160, 540.54, 740.74, 909.09, 1250, 1538.46, 2000, 
2352.94, 2666.67, 2941.18, 3333.33, 3571.43, 3846.15, 4347.83, 4545.45, 5000]

ufrequency = [3.70, 3.84, 32.14, 17.49, 34.94, 46.80, 37.47, 61.12, 83.32, 106.10, 52.42, 72.22, 81.76, 93.64, 117.39, 127.69, 152.75]

yvalues = [88/90, 175/200, 76/99, 17/26, 30/53, 25/53, 11/27, 8/27, 4/15, 
7/30, 29/135, 5/27, 23/135, 22/135, 8/53, 37/265, 33/260]

uyvalues = [0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 4.94e-3, 4.67e-3, 4.37e-3, 3.93e-3, 3.70e-3, 3.60e-3, 3.46e-3, 3.32e-3, 3.2e-3]

plt.errorbar(frequency, yvalues, xerr=ufrequency, yerr = uyvalues, fmt = 'b+', label = "Data")
plt.show()
```

## defining the model function

```
def f(freq, C, R, d, mu):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(1+((R*d)/(2/mu*C*2*np.pi*freq))**2))
```

### define initial guesses for the parameters

```
C0 = 70000000
R0 = 0.01012
d0 = 0.0004
mu0 = 1.256629e-6

p0 = [C0, R0, d0, mu0]

name = ["C", "R", "d", "mu"]

tmodel = np.linspace(100, 5000, 1000)

ystart = f(tmodel,*p0)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, frequency, yvalues, p0, sigma=uyvalues, absolute_sigma=True)
```

Comment: Even without the sigmas I get the warning and the fit doesn't work. It is likely that either the starting parameters or the function `f` are wrong.

Comment: I agree, I tried plotting the default values and they yield values of 1 all over, which is very far from how the values look like.

Comment: If you plot `f` for your initial guesses, you will see that the function is `1` all the time suggesting that the part `((R*d)/(2/mu*C*2*np.pi*freq))**2` is close to 0. so that you have `1/sqrt(1 + 0) = 1`. So you will have to play with the parameters a bit and then it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your model us overdetermined: note that it onky depends on the product `d*R`, so there's no way to find these two separately. Ditto for `mu*C`.